# CentOS 6.5 Internet Issue Troubleshooting

Tags: centos, networking, internet

I have a `CentOS 6.5` server running at a remote location
that I access using SSH through port forwarding on a router.

Everything was working fine until today when I found I can
no longer access the internet from the server.

I can still remote SSH into it and it still has it's
static IP address, gateway etc I just can't use the internet.

If I use the servers Ethernet cable in a different computer
that one can access the internet fine

But if I try ping I instantly get the error

```
# ping google.com
# ping: unknown host google.com
```

Does anyone have any steps to recommend towards figuring out why?

**

Content of file `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search DOMAINNAME.LOCAL domainname.local
nameserver 192.168.2.9
nameserver 192.168.2.16
```

Content of file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`:

```
DEVICE="eth1"
BOOTPROTO="static"
HWADDR="34:40:B5:89:85:BE"
IPADDR=192.168.2.45
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.2.254
DNS1=192.168.2.9
DNS2=192.168.2.16
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="bde2561c-9882-4e50-9e3a-22e44f6a5005"
```

Result of `nslookup google.com 192.168.2.9`

```
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Result of `nslookup google.com 192.168.2.16`

```
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Result of `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8`

```
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Result of `nslookup google.com 8.8.4.4`

```
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Result of `netstat -rn`

```
197.81.19.48    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 eth0
10.254.254.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 as0t0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
169.254.95.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 usb0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
```

Comment: Somehow name resolving fails on your server. Verify the name servers configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: I've added the resolv.conf contents to my question, I also have DNS settings in my network script which I will add as well

Comment: what happens when you try `nslookup google.com 192.168.2.9`, and `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8`? Maybe a firewall prevents you from using the nameservers configured, or they can not be reached, or the nameservers have been changed and the other computer is getting different nameservers from DHCP.

Comment: I will add the output of the nslookup to the question

Comment: Have you tried the `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8` variant? And did you compare the name server configuration between the two hosts?

Comment: I didn't I'll try that now

Comment: I had the same error as the other two, I tried 8.8.4.4 as well

Answer (score 1):

What does your host routing table look like on the Server?

```
netstat -rn
```

It sounds like you have a local host based routing issue. The port forwarding for SSH still works because that has a local connection to your server.

Comment: Hello, I will add the output to the Question